# can we validate incomplete DTO property?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am new to spring-boot I'm trying to create validation custom like below.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class SpecificResponse extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
            logger.info("1");
            List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
            // String coba = requestContext.getInfo();
            for (FieldError error : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
            errors.add(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            for (ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getGlobalErrors()) {
            errors.add(error.getObjectName() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            ApiError apiError = new ApiError();
            apiError.setResponseCode("99");
            apiError.setResponseDesc(ex.getBindingResult().getFieldValue("field") + " Failed");
            apiError.setResponseError(errors.toString());
            return handleExceptionInternal(
                    ex, apiError, headers,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
        
        }
}
```

Below is my DTO class

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class LiteTimeCreateDTO {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "Customer Code is required")
    @NotFound
    @NotBlank
    private String customerCode;
     
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "Customer Code2 is required")
    @NotFound
    @NotBlank
    private String customerCode2;
    
    @Email
    private String customerCode3;
}
```

Below is my object sent by postman

```json
{
    // "customerCode": "as",
    "customerCode3": "as@agasdf.com",
    "customerCode2" : "ds"
}
```

Below is my endpoint in controller

```java
@GetMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<ApiSuccess> getData( @Valid @RequestBody(required = true) LiteTimeCreateDTO liteTimeCreateDTO,  @RequestHeader(value = "User-Access") String header,  BindingResult result){
      ApiSuccess dataError = new ApiSuccess();
      dataError.setResponseCode("00");
      dataError.setResponseDesc("Get Lite Time Success");
//    dataError.setResponseData(datas);
      return new ResponseEntity<ApiSuccess>(dataError, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Everything is fine, it's just that I'm curious how to validate the sent dto is incomplete? when I send only 2 data there is no result response in my postman. How to fix and get the error response since there is no response in my postman.

Comment: Can you add the code that defines the endpoint of your Controller in which you are trying to validate the DTO? Thanks!

Comment: I have added my controller. thanks

Comment: Do you have `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency in your project?

Comment: yes I have it, this validation working fine when I send 3 object but it will give no response if we send just 2 object

Comment: What do you mean by "validation working fine when I send 3 object"? If you send `"customerCode": ""` does it throw any error regarding invalid DTO?

Comment: yes that's correct, when I send ```"customerCode": "" ``` it give error response like required and blank error

Comment: That is weird indeed. Have you tried using `@NotBlank` only? It does the job of both `@NotNull` and `@NotEmpty`. What happens if you don't send `customerCode3` property?

Comment: I assume that @valid just work when we send complete property of DTO

Comment: No, that is not it. When you do not send the complete DTO, Jackson will use the default value for each property (depending on their types, for `String` it is null). Have you tried using @NotBlank only? What happens if you only don't send customerCode3 property? So that we can help you further we will need you to give us more information since we need to debug the application through you.

Comment: it still blank response. if I send 3 property but change name from ```customerCode3``` into ```username``` in postman. it will return ```[customerCode: must not be blank]```

Comment: If you don't send one of the properties and place a breakpoint in the line `ApiSuccess dataError = new ApiSuccess();` of your `getData()` method what is the value of the missing property in `liteTimeCreateDTO`?

Comment: I have tried to change return to string like ```success code``` but it still give blank response. I tried to give logger into exception if method of valid is run but it still give blank. Its not enter into exception I guess or maybe there is other exception method that can handle this exception ?

Comment: If you don't send one of the properties and place a breakpoint in the line `ApiSuccess dataError = new ApiSuccess();` of your `getData()` method what is the value of the missing property in `liteTimeCreateDTO`? Do you see any exceptions when you don't send one of the properties?

Comment: it give Exception has occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.YearMonth"

Comment: That is what you see in Postman. I am asking in your IDE, when you place a breakpoint in the line `ApiSuccess dataError = new ApiSuccess();` of your `getData()` method what is the value of the missing property in `liteTimeCreateDTO`?

Comment: I have edited my answer. it give class not found exception

Comment: That makes no sense. Where does `org.joda.time.YearMonth` come from?

Comment: ```Exception has occurred: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 6]"```

Comment: ```Exception has occurred: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException
"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser); nstd exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unxpected character ('/' (code 47)): mybe a (non-standard) comment? (nt recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parsr)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 6]"```

Comment: this is the response when I give break points. maybe it can give you some hint. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use comments in JSON. Use the following request body instead:

```json
{
    "customerCode3": "as@agasdf.com",
    "customerCode2": "ds"
}
```

Comment: woow, it works well. Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is data only, and if you include a comment, then it will be data too.

You could have a designated data element called "_comment" (or something) that should be ignored by apps that use the JSON data.

You would probably be better having the comment in the processes that generates/receives the JSON, as they are supposed to know what the JSON data will be in advance, or at least the structure of it.